# How can I sort file that include Total number just sort number in bash script

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have file of strings that contains numbers

Example: Result_.txt

```
bbb..3 Total:10
aaa.85 Total:3
aaa.89 Total:2
bbb.90 Total:1
aaa.93 Total:19
aaa.94 Total:6
```

I want sort the file by this way and directory save the same file:

```
aaa.93 Total:19
bbb..3 Total:10
aaa.94 Total:6
aaa.85 Total:3
aaa.89 Total:2
bbb.90 Total:1
```

I've tried with this command:

```
if grep ':' Result_.txt ;then
awk '{print $3}' & sort -rn Result_.txt
fi
```

But it does not work.

Comment: `sort -t : -k 2 -r -n file`?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help and efforts.you saved me.